# Can't map property when using MapStruct

Tags: java, object-object-mapping, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct library to map objects but I got this error:

Can't map property "java.util.Date aDate" to "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement ADATE". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement map(java.util.Date value)".

My question: WHERE should I decleare this mapping method?

Comment: What does your current mapping look like?  That will inform the answer to the question.  AKA, can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I solved this issue by writing another class:

```
public class DateMapper {

    public JAXBElement<XMLGregorianCalendar> map(Date value) {

        // conversion here

        return atswer;
    }
}
```

and using this annotation:

```
@Mapper(uses=DateMapper.class)
```

Answer (score 12):

There are two alternatives:

- Make your mapper an abstract class instead of an interface and implement that method directly in the mapper class
- Implement the method on another class and declare this one as "used" by your mapper; See the [reference guide](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#datatype-conversions) for further details

Btw. the mapping should be done automatically if you are using `XMLGregorianCalendar` or `JAXBElement<XMLGregorianCalendar>` instead of the `JAXBElement` raw type.