# Can't map property String to JAXBElement<String> using MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct, jaxbelement

so I was playing a bit with Mapstruct, reading the reference Documentation for the Version 1.1.0.Final, and arrived at the point:
[implicit type conversions](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#implicit-type-conversions)

where is defined the following statement:

> Between JAXBElement < T> and T

I tried that, but the error what I received was:

```
Can't map property "java.lang.String xmlElement" "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<java.lang.String> xmlElement". 
Consider to declare/implement a mapping method:
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<java.lang.String> map(java.lang.String value)".
```

I know thisi is the same thread as[Can't map property when using MapStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672216/cant-map-property-when-using-mapstruct) but since then Mapstruct released a new version.

Am I doing something wrong or this feature really is missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping from `JAXBElement<T>` to `T` works out of the box. For the reverse you need to make sure that the `ObjectFactory`(ies) are in the `Mapper#uses`, MapStruct uses those methods to create the types.

You can also have a look at [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/tree/master/integrationtest/src/test/resources/jaxbTest) integration test.

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens on Java 9 or higher and you use implementation of type JAXBElement from maven library (in my case`'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'`) make sure it is on the classpath of the annotation processor - this resolved the issue for me.

Comment: How to specify the classpath of javax.xml.bind etc  for annotation processor in Gradle ?

Comment: Add dependency into compileOnly or compile configuration like so -  `compileOnly('...')` or `compile('...')` where ... is your library.

Answer (score 0):

If your JAXBElement was generated by a wsdl client generator (eg. xjc) you need to provide the corresponding ObjectFactory.class generated by the client generator:

```
@Mapper(uses = ObjectFactory.class)
public interface OrderMapper {
    Order orderEntityToExternalOrder(OrderEntity orderEntity);
}
```

See:
[MapStruct 1.0.0.Beta1 is out with JAXB support, custom factories, decorators and more](https://mapstruct.org/news/2014-03-05-mapstruct-1_0_0_Beta1-with-JAXB-support-factories-decorators-and-more/)